# Forecasting - Population Death Rates

Tags: regression, forecasting, survival, population, weibull-distribution

Wondering if you can help me out with this problem:

- I have 2 closed populations of products (call it Product X, and Product Y).
- Population Size of each product 10 million each (Product X = 10 million, Product Y = 10 million)
- Product X was the older generation of the product
- Product Y is the latest and greatest version and is deemed to last much longer in durability than Product X
- I have 78 months of death rates (or destruction rates) data on Product X and 29 months of death rates on Population Y. Overall about 58% of the population X died (was destroyed) after 78 months and about 5.2% of Population Y is dead so far (after 29 months)
- We will continue to accumulate Population Y death rates every month (i.e. month 30, 31,....78 in to the future) but Population X statistics are no longer tracked (other than 78 months of data)

Can you recommend a way to forecast future Population Y death rates by month (i.e. for months 30 to 78) with taking both population X and Population Y data into account?

I am thinking of fitting a regression model of the type ProductY_t = ProductY_{t-j} +... ProductX_{t-k} where j and k are different lags. I should  (1) remove trend and seasonality from each series, (2) Use these series to fit a regression model of ProductY as a function of previous ProductY values (AR-style) and previous ProductX values.

Does this approach seem reasonable? I am not sure i would implement this in R.
If interested, here is the R data for my problem:

```
Reporting_Month <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78)

Population_X_DeathRates <- c(0,0.004,0.016,0.024,0.02,0.005,0.004,0.005,0.007,0.009,0.008,0.012,0.017,0.008,0.016,0.027,0.026,0.016,0.015,0.014,0.008,0.01,0.01,0.015,0.016,0.008,0.009,0.02,0.016,0.008,0.01,0.008,0.005,0.008,0.008,0.01,0.008,0.005,0.013,0.011,0.01,0.007,0.006,0.004,0.003,0.006,0.006,0.006,0.005,0.004,0.007,0.009,0.008,0.003,0.005,0.004,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.001,0,0.001,0,0.001,0.001)

Population_Y_DeathRates <- c(0.002,0.002,0.003,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.003,0.003,0.002,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.002,0.003,0.002,0.001,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

population_DF <- data.frame (Reporting_Month,Population_X_DeathRates,Population_Y_DeathRates)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend another approach entirely. Instead of a regression model of dubious theoretical rigor, apply a Kaplan-Meier or Nelson-Aalen estimator to the right-censored time-to-event data for each of the products. These methods allow you to estimate the survivor curve, or the probability of survival from time t to time t+1. To estimate the time to failure, simply take the are under the curve (i.e. Sum the survival probabilities across time periods). Many packages in R and other statistical software platforms have Kaplan-Meier and Nelson-Aalen functions, as well as functions to compare survivor curves. If you are worried about the computation time, you have 10M samples per product, so you can form quite strong inferences using just a fraction of the data on each product. Or you could find a package that is highly scalable, but you won't get much payoff from it other than saying you can do survival/failure/event-history analysis on large datasets.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I will definitely take this suggestion into consideration and perhaps look at an ensemble model.

Comment: If it ends up working, or if you find this answer acceptable, please check it. If you find it useful, please upvote it. Thank you.